# ngOptions compare by value

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ng-options

I have a webserver (node.js) that serves a JSON file containing a list of languages in the following format: `{ "en" : "English", "fr" : "French" }` (and so on). And a separate JSON that is dictionary of settings: `{ "currentLanguage" : "en" }` (there are other settings).

The select is as follow:

```
<select ng-options="for (code, name) in languages track by code" ng-model="config.currentLanguage"></select>
```

However this always results in a blank option being added and selected. This is because is compares the value by reference and not by value. Is there a way to force it to use value instead? It seems like a pretty common thing, to have the current selection data separate to the data used to generate the options, or is there another way I should be doing this that gets around this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure your issue comes from reference checking ; the syntax you are using ignores the optional "select" parameter, which leads me to assume that the default behaviour of binding the value is in action. Which means, you are binding a name to a config.currentLanguage that seems to initially hold a "code" value. I think this might be the reason you can't initially select it : you are looking for a "en" in a list only containing "English".

To solve this, assuming you indeed want to store the code, you should write your ng-options as follows :

```
ng-options = "code as name for (code, name) in countries track by code"
```

Comment: Oh I assumed the `track by` would mean all the tracking was done by the following expression.

Comment: track by only tells angular to check code to determine if two items are identical : if another item with the same track by value is encountered, it is skipped. Otherwise, your ng-repeat will throw an error when he finds a duplicate. Did the line solve your issue or are you still encountering some unusual behaviour ?